JAX-RS client response readEntity(Class) with custom deserializer
I have spring boot application where i call other downstream service using javax ws Client.  When i get Response from any service i deserialize using readEntity() method of Response. I am getitng deserialization and i want to introduce my own custom deserializer every time i execute readEntity().  How can i give javax ws custom deserializer.
    Response response = client.post();
    response.readEntity(ReturnClass);

Here i want readEntityto use custom deserializer.

The class to use is jakarta.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader. You should be able to register a custom class. That should be possible on the ClientBuilder that you use to create client, but possibly also on client itself.
